# Manipulation with user and system environment variables from command line in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, environment-variables

I've been using following commands to set/remove user/system environment variables:

SYSTEM:

```
setx -m PATH "%PATH%C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;"
```

USER:

```
setx VAR1 "CONTENT OF VAR1"
```

Later I've  found those limitations:

1. If the `%PATH%` is too long then I get following warning and the `%PATH%` variable is truncated:

> WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

2. As the help for `setx` command says:

> When you use Setx.exe to clear an environment variable value, the
>   environment variable name is not affected

In other words when I run `setx -m OCVLIBDIR ""` then the `OCVLIBDIR` will not be deleted but rather empty.

How can I overcome those limitations?

PS: I prefer tools that are part of Windows 10 (e.g. PowerShell) but it is not problem to use also 3rd party tools (although it seems to me like overkill).

PPS: I know it is possible to edit variables via windows GUI, registers or some 3rd party GUI tools but I prefer scripts because I can have scripted multiple scenarios and fast switch between them.This is useful when I'm experimenting with various libraries on my system (e.g. various versions of opencv etc.).

Comment: Two minutes on google: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Comment: @Ouroborus I've found this page but: 1. there is not explicitly shown differences between user and system environment variables 2. it is not shown how to append (or concatenate) variables as I've did in %PATH% example. I'm looking for complete solution that works because I'm not PowerShell guru (I'm from Unix world).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PowerShell

[This TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) describes the basics.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675792/367865) describes getting system vs user environment variables (which was only hinted at in the first article). `"Machine"` for system, `"User"` for the current user, and `"Process"` for the current process which works for getting the final system/user combo.

PowerShell concatenation is talked about in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-to-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell). You can assemble strings using `+` to concatenate or use substitution as in `"{0} {1}" -f "Hello","World"`.

Parenthesis are used to group constructs together.

Variables are un-typed, undeclared, and start with `$`.

Putting it all together gets you something like:

```
$path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","User")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",$path+";C:\Temp","User")
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","User"))+";C:\Temp","User")
```

[This article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-one-liner-deleting-environment-variables) describes how to delete environment variables (`$null` is a special variable):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MyTestVariable",$null,"User")
```

Changes to the environment variables done this way are globally available.

---

### CMD

`reg.exe` can add, change, and delete registry entries. Environment variables live in the registry. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18899441/367865) talks about using `reg` to delete environment variables.

For user environment variables:

```
reg DELETE HKCU\Environment /v envvarname
```

For system environment variables:

```
reg DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v envvarname
```

(`HKCU` is interchangeable with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. `HKLM` is interchangeable with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.)

(Note that `CMD` treats empty environment variables the same as non-existent environment variables. I understand, though, that you're trying to purge the variable from the system.)

Comment: How to drop the path form environment variable after using your methed "[Environment]::SetEnvironmen..." to create.

Comment: @yode In my first example, the original `PATH` is first stored in `$path`. In that case, reverting to the original `PATH` would be something like `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",$path,"User")`.